# Cambiar posicion de texto

Tags: mysql

En una columna (`nombres`) de una tabla (`empleados`) de mi base de datos, tengo `1600 datos.` Pero esos datos no están en la posición que deseo. Me explico

La columna tiene nombres de personas, por ejemplo `Garcia, Pepe`, mi idea es **actualizarla** y que el resultado final sea `Pepe Garcia`.

```
    nombres
    ========
    GARCIA, PEPE
    GARCIA, JUAN
    GONZALEZ, JAVIER
    MANOLO
    .....
```

Tengo dos problemas:

El primero es que al usar la sentencia:

`update empleados set nombres = CONCAT(substring_index(nombres, ',', -1), ' ', substring_index(nombres, ',', 1));`

Me crea un espacio en blanco al principio de cada nombre. Y el segundo problema es que en los campos que solo hay un nombre, en este caso `MANOLO`, al ejecutar esa misma sentencia me muestra `MANOLO MANOLO`

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que quieres y suponiendo que le formato de todos los nombres es el mismo, es decir, "Apellido, Nombre" lo que se me ocurre es hacer un split por la coma que en MySQL es la función SUBSTRING_INDEX. De esta forma separamos lo que hay antes de la coma y lo que hay después. Sería algo así:

```
UPDATE empleados SET 
       nombres = TRIM(CONCAT(substring_index(nombres, ',', -1), ' ', substring_index(nombres, ',', 1))) 
WHERE INSTR(nombres, ',') > 0;
```

Con SUBSTRING_INDEX obtenemos los apellidos y los nombres por separado. TRIM nos elimina los espacios blancos del principio y del final. INSTR comprueba que la actualización se aplique sólo a aquellos registros que contengan una coma (evitando que MANOLO se repita).

He hecho algunas pruebas y me ha funcionado así como deseas aunque las funciones que se usan pueden depender de la versión que uses. No obstante, el concepto es el mismo.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: ¿No debería ser un `update` en vez de un `select`?

Comment: @xerox, update si lo que quieres es actualizar los campos de la tabla, pero en tu pregunta no has indicado que quieras actualizar o recoger los datos, de ahí la confusión

Comment: @Juanant Perdona, se me escapó ese dato. Mi idea es actualizar. Lo modifico ahora mismo

Comment: @Juanant ¿Alguna idea de como poder hacerlo?

Comment: estoy mirando por ahí, pero yo no soy el que te contestó jaja, es @MrSman

Comment: Ya lo tengo solucionado y he podido hacer el cambio con la siguiente sentencia: `update empleados set nombres = CONCAT(substring_index(nombres, ',', -1), ' ', substring_index(nombres, ',', 1));`. Gracias!!

Comment: @Juanant El unico problema que me presenta es que como primer caracter me pone un espacio

Comment: @Juanant Ya tengo modificada de nuevo la pregunta

Comment: Haz lo siguiente para eliminar los espcaios del principio y del final: UPDATE empleados SET nombres = TRIM(CONCAT(substring_index(nombres, ',', -1), ' ', substring_index(nombres, ',', 1)));

Comment: @MrSman Funcionó! Y el segundo problema que tengo, ¿hay alguna solución? Para que `MANOLO` no salga repetido

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001217/update-mysql-with-if-condition
En la respuesta de esta pregunta, puedes ver que se usa un `IF` en el update. Yo nunca he usado esto, pero puede que te sirva :)

Comment: Prueba a hacer: UPDATE empleados SET nombres = TRIM(CONCAT(substring_index(nombres, ',', -1), ' ', substring_index(nombres, ',', 1))) WHERE INSTR(nombres, ',') > 0;

Así compruebas que lo hace sólo para aquellos que contengan coma

Comment: @MrSman Perfecto! Ahora sí que sí. Muchas gracias!!